# How to create editable menu with parent and child in wordpress?

Tags: admin-menu

I have created a admin menu in wordpress, and it is a main menu, I do have one parent page and also associated with that there are some child pages. I want to get the images of that child pages needs to be displayed in the menu also, links to the child pages like button. How can i do this in wordpress? wp_get_nav_menu_items function.

structure is below.

```
Parent-A
    some description of parent-A page
    child-A->child-A page feature Image and two buttons
    child-B->child-B page feature Image and two buttons
    child-C->child-C page feature Image and two buttons
Parent-B
    some description of parent-B page
    child-D -> child-D page feature Image and two buttons
    child-E -> child-E page feature Image and two buttons
    child-F -> child-F page feature Image and two buttons
```

Answer (score -1):

WordPress has some functions to help work with lists of objects. These are especially helpful when working with the nav menu objects or the query object.

[`wp_filter_object_list()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_filter_object_list) takes an array of objects and filters them by a given set of criteria. You get a result that only contains objects that match your criteria.

Once you get a list of the menu items you'd like to loop through, you can check conditions to output different things. For example, what's the depth? What is the parent post id? etc. 
After that, grab the relevant information from the associated post id.

I hope that helps.

Comment: First I need to get all the menu Items from admin side. How can I do that?

Comment: What have you tried? We can analyse the code you've used and try to make a better code explaining what to do and what not to do. When there is no attempts from your side it looks like you want to hire somebody for free.

Comment: You posted the function: `wp_get_nav_menu_items()`

Comment: I just want a solution how it can be done in wordpress, because once I added in the admin, the menu will appear, but i couldn't find where i can add the code?

Comment: Read the documentation for these functions. Try working in your functions.php file in your theme or within a plugin. I'm sorry, but I'm not going to write the code for you.